# How to create a tcp service in traefik 2.2.1

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a tcp service like this in kubernetes cluster followed by official [docs](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/services/):

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: TraefikService
metadata:
  name: app-mysql
spec:
    tcp:
      services:
        my-service:
           loadBalancer:
             servers:
               - address: '<private-ip-server-1>:<private-port-server-1>'
               - address: '<private-ip-server-2>:<private-port-server-2>'
```

and I only see the traefik service in lens, in the traefik dashboard found nothing:

[image]

What should I do to create a TCP Service in traefik 2.2.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you'd like to talk to TCP services running in Kubernetes. For TCP you don't need really need a `TraefikService`, you can just use an `IngressRouteTCP` resource.

You can see in the [docs](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-ingressroutetcp) that the `IngressRouteTCP` can talk directly to a K8s service.

[image: image1]

Similarly to the [example](https://docs.traefik.io/reference/dynamic-configuration/kubernetes-crd/#resources) you can have something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteUDP
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-udp-route
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - myentrypoint
  routes:
    - match: HostSNI(`mysql.example.com`)
      services:
        - name: app-mysql  K8s Service
          port: 3306
```

Notes:

- `TraefikService` can be used for in regular `IngressRoute` resources, and not supported in TCP/UDP case today)
- Not sure how you plan to load balance a MySQL service though, as this typically happens at the application level or you need a particular proxy that handles your reads/writes and data consistency)

✌️

Comment: I suppose with HostSNI(`*`) all the incoming TCP traffic should be redirected to the TCP service, no?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's the case.